# Log off when iexplorer is closed

Tags: vbscript

Hi im new to vbscript and cant find any information on how to detect when an created object is closed.

I have the following code:

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objExplorer.Navigate "//IDM/jsps/login/Login.jsf"
objExplorer.Visible = true
objExplorer.ToolBar = false
objExplorer.MenuBar = false
objExplorer.StatusBar = false
objExplorer.AddressBar = false
objExplorer.Width = 1000
objExplorer.Height = 600
objExplorer.Resizable = false
```

I am trying to get windows to log off when ie is closed, I have the following code to log off off which works, how would i call this on ieclose?

```
WshShell.Run "C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /l",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to check object HWND property and handle the error.

```
On Error Resume Next
Do Until Err
    h = objExplorer.HWND
    WScript.Sleep 50
Loop

WshShell.Run "C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /l"
```

[EDIT] Or maybe this is very closer to your needs:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "mshta.exe //IDM/jsps/login/Login.jsf", 1, True
    .Run "C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe /l"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WScript.Shell.Run` with waiting instead of `InternetExplorer.Application` with looping:

```
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL =  1
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "iexplore.exe http://www.google.com", SW_SHOWNORMAL, True
WScript.Echo "Run done."
```

Comment: Yes, of course that's better in case @stefan not need customize options (like .ToolBar, .MenuBar, etc).